# Creating a new binary column by series mapping from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

Good day,

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict_one = {M:[1, 3, 5, 10, 12, 14], A:[2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]}
```

I wish to map the dictionary to a data frame with the respected values inside the keys. However, I wish to turn the keys M and A into binary numbers where M =1 and A = 0 and place them in a new column like this. The new mapped column should map the new values based on the 'object' column which is an already existing column in existing data frame.

```
 object    new_column
   1           1
   2           0
   3           1
   4           0
   5           1
   6           0
```

How do I go about doing this? Help would be truly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Hey @sacul I saw you post something but it deleted!

Comment: I deleted it because I did it wrong at first, but now edited it... It should work, I think!

Comment: it seems the `new_column` is 1 when `object` is odd, else 0? if that's the case, then you could just do `df['new_column'] = (df.object % 2 == 1).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your dataframe using a list comprehension and then use `map`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([(x,key) for key,i in dict_one.items() for x in i],
                  columns=['object', 'new_column'])
      .sort_values('object'))

df['new_column'] = df.new_column.map({'M':1,'A':0})

>>> df
    object  new_column
0        1           1
6        2           0
1        3           1
7        4           0
2        5           1
8        6           0
9        7           0
10       9           0
3       10           1
11      11           0
4       12           1
12      13           0
5       14           1
13      15           0
```

You could even do it all in one go using `replace` instead of `map`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([(x,key) for key,i in dict_one.items() for x in i],
                  columns=['object', 'new_column'])
      .sort_values('object')
      .replace({'new_column':{'M':1, 'A':0}}))
```

**EDIT** Based on your comments, it seems like you are starting from a dataframe, which I am assuming looks something like:

```
>>> df
   object
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
```

In this case, I think your best bet is to create a new mapping dictionary, and just use `map`:

```
new_dict = {x:(1 if key=='M' else 0) for key, i in dict_one.items() for x in i}
# {1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 10: 1, 12: 1, 14: 1, 2: 0, 4: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 9: 0, 11: 0, 13: 0, 15: 0}

df['new_column'] = df.object.map(new_dict)

>>> df
   object  new_column
0       1           1
1       2           0
2       3           1
3       4           0
4       5           1
5       6           0
```

Comment: Hey @sacul I already have the dataframe! So how caN i do it then?

Comment: I meant to ask how do I apply it to an existing data frame. Like I do not need to create one, I already have one but need to apply this to it. Lets just say I already have a data frame with the column 'object' @sacul

Comment: I wish to create the new column in an existing dataframe @sacul

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks much !

Answer (score 2):

We can just using `np.where`

```
np.where(df.object.isin(dict_one['A']),0,1)
Out[690]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: @DeepakM This is better than my answer, and should be the accepted one in my opinion :)